# VLC jpeg streaming

Tags: c#, streaming, udp, jpeg, libvlc

I'm writing a application, which retrieve rtsp stream from camera then do multicast streaming, at one point I need jpeg streaming in case
camera connection is unsuccesfull.

My command line arguments is :

CODE: SELECT ALL

```
string[] args = new string[] {
                "-I", "dummy", 
                "--ignore-config",              
                @"--plugin-path=plugins",
                "--fake-file",  
            "#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=2000,width=800,height=600}:std{access=udp,mux=mpjpeg,dst=239.255.12.42:1234}",
            };
```

I also tried some other thinks like "--loop" vs. but it does not work, so what am I supposed to do ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

mux=mpjpeg works only under HTTP not UDP.

Since you are doing multicast then it is obvious change is mux. you can use mux=ts.